# How to view datasource in SSRS 2019

Tags: reporting-services, datasource

I recently migrated from SSRS 2012 to SSRS 2019 and I am having some trouble finding my way around the report server.

My question is, **how can I see the data source being used by a report?**

In 2012, I can see the data source by clicking on the report name, as circled below.[image]

Once you click on the report name, you are brought to this screen and you can see how your data source is set up.[image]

BUT... I am not able to follow the same steps in 2019. This same report in 2019 looks like this. As you can see in this picture, I am not able to click in the report name to access the data source. The report name isn't highlighted for me to click into.[image]

**How do I navigate to where I can see how the data source is set up for a deployed report in SSRS 2019?**

EDIT: After posting the above, I messed around a bit more and I came to this page. **I think I am supposed to see data source as an option in the black panel but it's not there. Why not?**
[image]

EDIT: **Resolved. It was a permission issue.**

Comment: Not sure baout 2019 but on 2016, go back to the folder where the report resides, click the 3 dots in the top corner of the report and then click 'manage'

Comment: @AlanSchofield That's basically the window I am showing in my last screenshot. I seem to have navigated my way into the "Properties" of the report. But for some reason, I am not seeing "Data Source" as an option for me to explore.

Comment: I posted before your edit...

You should post you solution as an answer - you can answer your own questions on SO